# Making an array of chars

Tags: c

I have a problem, I have to make an array of characters, starting with just one character and after all characters run out, make 2 digit ones, and when they run out, make 3 digit ones, etc. So here is how I go about that:

```
char myChar = malloc(8);

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
mychar[i] = i + 'a';
}
```

I don't know where to go when 1 char words run out. Nested for loops? How to add up chars? With strcat()?

EDIT: Sorry if my question is not clear. Basically it is assignment to make a brute force hash cracker. I have a has part working, comparing strings working, only problem is with this thing generating symbols.
How this works - I make a word, send it to has function and check result with target hash. If they are same, voila.
So here I try to make an array of characters starting from 1 character and going up.
So I make 'a', check it, if no avail, I change it to 'b', etc, etc up to 'z'.
When I get to 'z' I want it to start anew with 2 characters, 'aa', then 'ab', then 'ac' up to 'zz'. When this runs out I want it to start with 'aaa' then 'aab' etc, etc. up to 8 digits.
I know it will take huge time and all.
But the problem I face is concantenation of chars. How do I write a loop so on first round it is only one symbol, on second round it is two and so on. I hope this explained a little bit.

Comment: `malloc` returns a pointer to the memory it allocates. How can you change your current 'array' declaration to be a pointer?

Comment: Doesn't make sense at all. 2 digit arrays of characters... what's that? What exactly are 1 char words? What do you mean "add up chars"?

Comment: As far as I understood , you want one array of `a,b,c,...,z` then `aa,bb,cc,...,zz `and so on btw question is not clear

Comment: @djechkin I have provided the code, I don't know where to go next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses nested loops.
The outer loop is endless; replace it by a loop of a length you need. The inner loop changes the string to the next one: "aa" to ba", "ba" to "ca", ..., "zz" to "aaa", etc. It changes individual characters in the string instead of using `strcat`.

Note that the output looks a bit backward; i guess it's not too bad because it's not very important in which order to check all the guesses, as long as you check them all.

```
char str[100] = ""; // initialize all characters to '\0'
char min = 'a';
char max = 'z';
for (;;)
{
    int i;
    int increase_length = 1; // a flag to detect transitions like "zzz" => "aaaa"
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i]++ == max) // change to next character and check whether it was 'z'
        {
            str[i] = min;
        }
        else
        {
            increase_length = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (increase_length)
        str[i] = min;
    puts(str);
}
```